# Dynamic web module and Ejb cannot be both selected in Eclipse Project Facets

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to create a Stateless bean in a maven project in Eclipse, so i selected the EJB module in project Facets but i cannot apply this configuration due to the error message that eclipse is showing: 
Dynamic web module 3.0 and Ejb module 3.0 cannot be both selected

here's my pom.xml:

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>stateless-ejb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Stateless EJB web app Project</name>
  <description>This is the Stateless EJB project</description>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.redhat.training</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All
            of them are provided by JBoss EAP -->

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
            JBoss EAP -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
            JBoss EAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
            JBoss EAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


         <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need to explicitly reference this version, or else there will be an exception
        due to a bug in Arquilian -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>stateless-ejb</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <extensions>false</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>com.google.guava,org.slf4j
                            </Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- This profile skips all tests, though you can tune
                it to run just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Separate profiles are provided for running all tests, including
                Arquillian tests that execute in the specified container -->
           <!-- Use this profile if you just want to build a WAR file without running any unit tests -->
           <!-- Run like this:  mvn clean package -Pdefault -->
            <id>default</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that
                executes tests in a remote JBoss EAP instance -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote or, simply run: mvn test -->
            <!-- To make it easy to run tests from within JBDS, this profile is set as active by default -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I tried to change the version of the two modules but nothing happens, it seems that they're in conflict.
the funny thing is that it works fine for my friend project.

Any Help!